# Requesting page insight for Facebook getting error "Graph returned an error: An unknown error has occurred. "

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email','manage_pages','pages_manage_cta','publish_pages','publish_actions'];
```

giving permissions.

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/Facebook/insight.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

facebook Insight code.

```
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
```

Get user groups detail

```
$requestPageInsights = $fb->request('GET', '/1364467436924381/insights/, $accessToken');
```

//Make a batch request

```
$batch = ['page-insights' => $requestPageInsights];

try {
$responses = $fb->sendBatchRequest($batch);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
```

When Graph returns an error

```
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
```

When validation fails or other local issues

```
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}
```

Graph returned an error: An unknown error has occurred.

Comment: You should rather be getting an error saying “Invalid query”, telling you that no insights metric was specified ...

Comment: I also specified but it also not worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just experienced the same issue.
The error seems to be with batched requests - The solution for us was to change the code to do the requests individually.