# Facebook Marketing Api - running on loop throws "AuthorizationException An unknown error has occurred." (on 2nd time)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using Facebook Ads SDK and trying to add users to a custom audience list. As there is a [10000 data limit at a time](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/guides/custom-audiences), for future proof I am trying to add data in a loop.

However, when it hits the second time, it throws an error.

#### 1.

```
public function test($audienceId, $data)
    Api::init($appId, $appSecret, $token);

    $audience = new CustomAudience($audienceId);

    $schema = [
       CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::EMAIL,
       CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::PHONE,
       //...
    ];

    foreach (array_chunk($data, 500) as $chunk) {
        $audience->addUsersMultiKey($chunk, $schema, true);
    }
}

// And run as

$class = new FbTestClass();
$class->test($audienceId, $data);
```

If the `addUsersMultiKey()` runs 1 time, it works perfectly, however if it runs 2 times, it throws an error

> FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException - An unknown error has occurred.

---

#### 2 Then I tried to move `App:init()` part to `__construct()`, but the issue persists.

```
public function __construct() {
   Api::init($appId, $appSecret, $token);
}

public function test($audienceId) {
   $audience = new CustomAudience($audienceId);

   $schema = [
       CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::EMAIL, //...
   ];

   $audience->addUsersMultiKey($chunk, $schema, true);
}

// And run as:

$class = new FbTestClass();

foreach (array_chunk($data, 500) as $chunk) {
   $class->test($audienceId, $chunk);
}
```

---

#### 3. I tried looping outside of the `test()` function, and keeping `App::init()` inside the `test()` function, so `App::init()` gets called multiple times. Still same issue.

---

[This answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44716546/4705339) says to do the requests individually but how is it possible to do that? But, didn't I try all possible scenarios?

> The error seems to be with batched requests - The solution for us was to change the code to do the requests individually.

---

I believe it's about the runtime because when I refresh, it works alright; so I don't think it's throttling issue (I also tried to `sleep(10)`, in fact it works on refresh).

How can I overcome this issue?

- Maybe there is a way to destroy `App` instance? Or is there a way to create a new `App` instance to overwrite previous one?
- I saw a [batch request in the facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/asyncrequests) but couldn't figure out how to use it with my use-case (custom audience & addUsersMultiKey()).

---

Stack Trace:

```
An unknown error has occurred. {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (FacebookAds\\Http\\Exception\\AuthorizationException(code: 1): An unknown error has occurred. at /home/vagrant/Code/myApp/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php:165)    
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/vagrant/Code/myApp/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Client.php(215): FacebookAds\\Http\\Exception\\RequestException::create()
#1 /home/vagrant/Code/myApp/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Request.php(286): FacebookAds\\Http\\Client->sendRequest()
#2 /home/vagrant/Code/myApp/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Api.php(165): FacebookAds\\Http\\Request->execute()
#3 /home/vagrant/Code/myApp/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Api.php(214): FacebookAds\\Api->executeRequest()
#4 /home/vagrant/Code/myApp/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Object/CustomAudience.php(537): FacebookAds\\Api->call()

#5 is where I execute the code:
$audience->addUsersMultiKey($chunk, $schema, true);
```

---

**Update: 4 I also tried same thing with graph-sdk**

```
$fb = new Facebook([
      'app_id' => env("FB_APP_ID"),
      'app_secret' => env("FB_APP_SECRET"),
      'default_graph_version' => 'v6.0',
      'default_access_token' => env("FB_ACCESS_TOKEN")
]);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
      $payload = [
          'schema' => $schema,
          'data' => $chunk->toArray()
      ];
      
      $requests[] = $fb->request("POST", "/$customAudienceId/users", ['payload' => $payload]);
}

$batchResponse = $fb->sendBatchRequest($requests);
```

Here, response array has both request. 1st one is successful, second one same issue.

```
$batchResponse contains:

responses: array:2 [▼
    0 => Facebook\FacebookResponse ▼
        body => // successful data returned...
    1 => Facebook\FacebookResponse ▼
        body => "{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"A5...464cGc22gi28Kb"}}"
```

Comment: Please include the exception trace, I've got a copy of the SDK here and it'd be easier to know where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Also, try to catch the exception, and get the actual response from it using `.. catch (\FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException $e) { var_dump($e->getResponse); }`

Comment: @DanielCosta I added to the question

Comment: I took a look at the SDK, following the trace. Couldn't find too much, maybe it's a bug in the graph api or the sdk itself. 

I was going to suggest you to file a bug report at facebook, but just saw you already did. :)

Comment: Yes, very weird issue. If i refresh, it works, but if i use it in the same runtime, it doesn't work. Do you think there is a way to destroy the Api instance and recreate it? Or do you have any theory that i can try? My experimental theory is: $session = new `$api = new Session(env("APP_ID"), env("APP_SECRET"), env("TOKEN"));
            $api = new Api(new Client(), $session); // do stuff // unset($api)` but no luck so far ‍♂️

Comment: I don't think you need to destroy the api instance. Because when you call `api::init` it makes a new Session, new Client and a new Api instance. It effectively replaces the last one. I think you should try to debug the actual curl request that the sdk is generating, and compare the first and the second. Try to find any difference in the headers, or in the query itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug, it was actually from my end.

When I was chunking, my indexes in chunks were preserving their indexes of actual array, and as it wasn't giving [0,1,2], it was causing the api call to fail.

`array_values($chunk);` should fix that issue.

*for Laravel's collection `$chunk->values()->toArray();`*

Comment: Anyway, the API should return a better error message probably. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @DanielCosta thanks - yeah would save me a day. `AuthorizationException` is far from descriptive

Answer (score 0):

I've posted this as a comment, but the formatting didn't help.

Add following lines to `FacebookAds/Http/Adapter/CurlAdapter.php` just before `$raw_response = $this->getCurl()->exec();`.

```php
$fp = fopen("/temp/log_" . uniqid() . ".txt", "w"); // change this to any file, but make sure it changes between requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
```

This way you can check the actual contents of the request being made. If the requests are the same, then it's definitely a facebook bug.

Edit: Exact code to put above `$raw_response`

```
curl_setopt($this->getCurl()->getHandle(), CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($this->getCurl()->getHandle(), CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
```

Comment: I tried to run this, the requests seem identical except first line: 1st (success) one: `Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped`; 2nd (failed) one: `Hostname graph.facebook.com was found in DNS cache`. Also another difference is, last line of 1st request shows `Connection #0 to host graph.facebook.com left intact`. edit: also at the bottom I see `HTTP error before end of send, stop sending` for failed request. I don't quite know which part to look and diagnose. Do you have any suggestions?